# Help making sense of Taylor series using MVT only

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I know the coefficients in Taylor series are cooked up to be equal to the derivatives of the original function. But it's still a bit vague to me how information at one single point give the entire function... so I'm trying to derive it using MVT. Kindly have a look at the attached picture.

[image: processed image of computation scan]
 [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQuwR.jpg)

From my attempt so far, I don't see any way of getting *factorial* terms in the denominators. Although it seems $\theta_i = \frac{1}{i+1}$ should fix the problem, but this proof looks beyond my depth. Any help?

If I apply MVT again on $f''$  :
$$f(a+h) = f(a) + hf'(a) + h^2\theta_1 f''(a) + h^3\theta_1\theta_2f'''(a+h\theta_1\theta_2\theta_3) $$
for some $\theta_i \in (0,1)$

My question is how to get rid of these $\theta_i$...

Comment: Rewrite the MVT in terms of an integral: $$\int_a^b f(t) dt = (b-a)f(\xi)$$ for $a\leq\xi\leq b$ and use repeated partial integration on the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: [quote]I know the coefficients in Taylor series are cooked up to be equal to the derivatives of the original function. But it's still a bit vague to me how information at one single point give the entire function...[/quote]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the defect in how good you can guess $f(a)$ from $x$ using function value and the first $k$ derivatives in the Taylor polynomial (that you get by considering coordinate shifts in polynomials):
$$
\phi_a(x)=f(x)-f(a)+f'(x)(a-x)+\frac12f''(x)(a-x)^2+...+\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(x)(a-x)^k.
$$
Obviously, $\phi_a(a)=0$.

This function has a derivative where almost everything cancels
\begin{align}
\phi_a'(x)&=f'(x)+[f''(x)(a-x)-f'(x)]+\left[\frac12f'''(x)(a-x)^2-f''(x)(a-x)\right]+...+\left[\frac1{k!}f^{(k+1)}(x)(a-x)^k-\frac1{(k-1)!}f^{(k)}(x)(a-x)^{k-1}\right]
\\
&=\frac1{k!}f^{(k+1)}(x)(a-x)^k
\end{align}

Now apply the **extended mean value theorem**
$$
\frac{\phi_a(x)-\phi_a(a)}{(a-x)^m-(a-a)^m}=\frac{\phi_a'(\tilde x)}{-m(a-\tilde x)^{m-1}}=-\frac1{m\cdot k!}f^{(k+1)}(\tilde x)(a-\tilde x)^{k+1-m}.
$$

Now rename $x=x_0$, then $a=x$ to get
$$
f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac12f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+...+\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k
+ \frac1{m\cdot k!}f^{(k+1)}(\tilde x)(x-\tilde x)^{k+1-m}(x-x_0)^m
$$

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for. I get till $${\phi_a}'(x) = \frac1{k!}f^{(k+1)}(x)(a-x)^k$$. Pretty clever way to use telescoping! I'll look up extended mean value theorem and get back. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I've seen it first in an "calculus for engineers" book that my father used in the 1960ies, the idea is certainly older.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're choosing these two functions for the extended MVT : 
$$f(t) = \phi_a(t)$$
$$g(t) = (a-t)^m$$

then letting $m = k+1$ should fix the remainder term. Looks I get this. Your father sounds like a great man and you're definitely lucky to still have access to his books!  Old is indeed gold! Thanks again for sharing this cool telescoping trick :) It made my day XD

Answer (score 2):

"I know the coefficients in Taylor series are cooked up to be equal to the derivatives of the original function. But it's still a bit vague to me how information at one single point give the entire function..."

It **doesn't**!  You also need the information that the entire function is "analytic".  That is, that it **can** be written as a power series **and** that the power series is equal to the function.  For example, the function equal to $e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x\ne 0$, f(0)= 0 is infinitely differentiable and the value or every derivative is 0 at x= 0.  So the "Taylor series" at x= 0 exists- and is identically 0.  But f(x) is not equal to 0 anywhere except at x= 0!